# How can I post links, pictures etc to my facebook page on behalf of my page using an app?

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

So I have an app on facebook which has permissions to publish_stream, manage_pages, well I'm so far able to post 'text' updates to my own profile where it shows 'via app name'.

Then I have tried to post from this app into my page on page's behalf.

I'm able to do that by `client.Post("/page name/feed", new { message = "abcd" });` (only text) **but if I try to post links, title or picture it still post's on my page, but with my profile like I'm sharing something on that page and does not post as my page.**

I'm using this method to post.

```
private void CheckAuthorization()
    {
        string app_id = "APP_ID";
        string app_secret = "APP_SECRET";
        string scope = "publish_stream,manage_pages,";

        if (Request["code"] == null)
        {
            Response.Redirect(string.Format(
                "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id={0}&redirect_uri={1}&scope={2}",
                app_id, Request.Url.AbsoluteUri, scope));
        }
        else
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> tokens = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            string url = string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={0}&redirect_uri={1}&scope={2}&code={3}&client_secret={4}",
                app_id, Request.Url.AbsoluteUri, scope, Request["code"].ToString(), app_secret);

            HttpWebRequest request = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;

            using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

                string vals = reader.ReadToEnd();

                foreach (string token in vals.Split('&'))
                {
                    //meh.aspx?token1=steve&token2=jake&...
                    tokens.Add(token.Substring(0, token.IndexOf("=")),
                        token.Substring(token.IndexOf("=") + 1, token.Length - token.IndexOf("=") - 1));
                }
            }

            string access_tokens = tokens["access_token"];

            var client = new FacebookClient(access_tokens);

            dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();

            parameters.message = "Check out this New Item";
            parameters.link = "https://www.example.com";
            parameters.picture = "http://www.example.com/images/img.jpg";
            parameters.name = "Item Title";
            parameters.caption = "Caption for the link";

            client.Post("/AllTheMed/feed", new { message = "lsjlsjlsjkldf" });

        }
    }
```

Comment: Please do not post your app secret, it is supposed to be kept secret. So please  regenerate it.  Also, Try using page access token to post and check if you solve your issue.

Comment: @Anvesh Saxena sorry I was in hurry, yes I have tried using page access token extended the token as well but no good

Answer (score 0):

in your code you only get USER access token. However, in order to post as page, you need to get PAGE access token. See here for more details: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/pages/

In 2 words, you need to do the following:

1. Authenticate the user and request the manage_pages permission
2. Get the list of pages the user manages using token from (1) - https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=USER_ACCESS_TOKEN
3. Parse the list and get the PAGE token - and use it to post to the feed.

Basically, before your

```
client.Post("/AllTheMed/feed", ...)
```

you should call **me/accounts** (here comes pseudocode):

```
var myAccounts = client.Get("/me/accounts");
var pageAccessToken = myAccounts.Single(x => x.pageName == MY_PAGE_NAME).access_token;

var pageClient = new FacebookClient(pageAccessToken);
pageClient.Post("/me/feed", ...)
```